# JSON.parse returns string instead of object

Tags: javascript, json, websocket

im writing a websocket client and i would like to receive messages as json strings. For this I need a login. And if the login isn't true i send a json string with nosuccess.
JSON String:

```
{"action":"login","args":["nosuccess"]}
```

On the client I'm using this to get the string:

```
WebSocket socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:2555/api");

socket.onmessage = function(evt) {
    console.log(evt.data);
    console.log(typeof(evt.data));
    onMessage(evt);
}
function onMessage(evt) {
var data = JSON.parse(evt.data);
var action = data.action;
var args = data.args;
console.log(data);
console.log(typeof(data));
console.log(action);
console.log(args);
```

But the type of data is a string...
But why?

evt.data returns:

```
 "{\"action\":\"login\",\"args\":[\"nosuccess\"]}"
```

data returns:

```
 {"action":"login","args":["nosuccess"]}
```

The WebSocket server is a jetty Server which sends a string and a string array in json parsed in json with gson.toJson(class) Gson by Google. The Class is a class containing String action and String array args.

Complete source code of websocket.js:

```
var socket;

function openWebsocket(adress) {
    socket = new WebSocket(adress);
    socket.onopen = function(evt) {
        console.log("Socket opened [" + adress + "]");
    };
    socket.onclose = function(evt) {
        loadPage("login.html");
        console.log("Socket closed [" + evt.code + "]");
    }
    socket.onmessage = function(evt) {
        onMessage(evt);
    }
    socket.onerror = function(evt) {
        console.log("Socket couldn't connect [" + evt.message + "]");
        showMessage("fa-exclamation-circle", "Socket couldn't be established!", 1000);
    }
}

function onMessage(evt) {
    var data = JSON.parse(evt.data);
    var action = data.action;
    var args = data.args;
    console.log(data);
    console.log(typeof(data));
    console.log(action);
    console.log(args);
    $(".card-container h3").html(data);

    if(action == "login") {
        if(args[0] == "success") {
            loadPage("dashboard.htm");
            currentpage = "dashboard.htm";
            showMessage("fa-check", "Du wurdest erfolgreich eingeloggt", 2000);
        } else if(args[0] == "nosuccess") {
            loadPage("login.html");
            currentpage = "login.html";
            showMessage("fa-exclamation-circle", "Falscher Benutzername oder falsches Passwort", 2000);
        } else if(args[0] == "unauthenticated") {
            loadPage("login.html");
            currentpage = "login.html";
            showMessage("fa-exclamation-circle", "Login failure: not authenticated", 2000);
        }
    }

}

function sendMessage(json) {
    $(".card-container h3").html(JSON.stringify(json));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
    socket.send(JSON.stringify(json));
}
```

If I change this line:

```
 var data = JSON.parse(evt.data);
```

to this:

```
var data = JSON.parse("{\"action\":\"login\",\"args\":[\"nosuccess\"]}");
```

Then it is a json object, but when I use evt.data then it is a string.
If I change the line to this:

```
    var data = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(evt.data));
```

Then it works, but why, normally it should do it with only one JSON.parse, should it?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/morutob/1/edit?js,console — I can't reproduce the problem. You must be mistaken about the value of `evt.data`.

Comment: If I write the value of evt.data in JSON.parse(); like JSON.parse( "{\"action\":\"login\",\"args\":[\"nosuccess\"]}"); in manually then it parse it to a object

Comment: @Quentin evt.data is a string which I explained in my post

Comment: If you write it manually and get an object, but get it from `evt.data` and don't … then what you are writing manually and what you are getting from `evt.data` are **different** so you must be mistaken about the value of `evt.data`.

Comment: But for the manually method I used the string which I got from evt.data. Why is this not the same?

Comment: You are changing it in some way. I can't see how based on what you've said in the question.

Comment: I added more information to post, hopefully you can help me!

Comment: I had the exact same problem, and it was a an object that was stringified twice

Answer (score 71, accepted):

This seems to be fairly consistent with *over*-stringified strings. For example I loaded a text file using `FileReader.readAsText` that came with `\n` and `\r` which rendered in the console, so I did - `(JSON.stringify(reader.result)).replace(/(?:\\[rn])+/g, '')` first to see the symbols, then to get rid of them. Taking that and running `JSON.parse()` on it converts it to a non-escaped string, so running `JSON.parse()` again creates an object.

If you do not stringify your string, it will convert to an object and often it is not necessary but if you have no control over the obtained value, then running `JSON.parse()` twice will do the trick.

Comment: +1. According to [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) `JSON.parse()` returns _"The Object, Array, string, number, boolean, or null value corresponding to the given JSON text."_ So, 1. I need to remember that JSON can be used to represent more than just objects (I think the confusing thing is that you can stringify strings) and 2. one must 'un-stringify' (parse) as many times as the JSON is stringified.

Answer (score 14):

@DerpSuperleggera is correct. The issue was indeed an *over*-stringified string

```
let arr = "[\"~#iM\",[\"is_logged_out_token\",false,\"token_type\",\"Bearer\"]]"
```

So to parse it as an object, I just ran it through `JSON.parse` twice and that did the trick!

```
let obj = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(arr))
```

Answer (score 7):

The checked response is correct in that it seems to be an issue of over-stringified strings. I came across it from using AWS Amplify AWSJSON type in my project. The solution that worked for me was to iterate multiple (twice) to get an object.

Wrote a simple JS function that when used to parse will return an object. There isn't really error checking, but a starting point.

```
    export function jsonParser(blob) {
       let parsed = JSON.parse(blob);
       if (typeof parsed === 'string') parsed = jsonParser(parsed);
       return parsed;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

As others have stated in the comments it seems that this issue has been solved. If you are receiving a response from the server as a "stringified object" then you can turn it into a normal object with *JSON.parse()* like so:

```
var stringResponse = '{"action":"login","args":["nosuccess"]}';

var objResponse = JSON.parse(stringResponse);

console.log(objResponse.args);
```

You can also try out the above code [here](http://jsbin.com/jirecapozu/1/edit?js,console).

As for why the server is returning a string when you really wanted an object, that really comes down to your backend code, what library you are using, and the transport protocol. If you just want your front-end code to work, use *JSON.parse*. If you want to edit how the backend responds, please provide more information.