# Serializing a model as Json in Django and parse it with JavaScripts JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, serialization

I am afraid I don’t understand what "serializing" means. If someone can explain I’d be grateful. I am serializing a Django model in Json as explained in the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/serialization/):

```
data = serializers.serialize("json", MyModel.objects.all())
```

In my HTML/JS I access the data as [recommended](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script):

```
{{ data|json_script:"data" }}
var myData = JSON.parse([document.getElementById('data').textContent]);
```

But instead of being an Object `myData` is a string. So I guess somehow I serialize twice or something.

I found a solution, `JSON.parse` works as expected on my `data` now:

```
data = json.loads(serializers.serialize("json", CoursePage.objects.child_of(self).live().public()))
```

But I guess I still don’t understand the meaning of "serializing" properly. The Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html#json.loads) say about `json.loads(s)`: "Deserialize s (a str instance containing a JSON document). Why do I have to deserialize before `JSON.parse` works?  The [description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) for `JSON.parse` states: "The JSON.parse() method parses a JSON string"? Which I thought Djangos serializer would gave me in the first place. I am confused.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42494823

Answer (score 2):

The `json_script` filter is for Python objects. But serialization is already the conversion of Python objects into JSON. So effectively you're converting it twice.

In your case I wouldn't bother with that filter. Just remove the `json.loads` and output the data directly where you need it:

```
var myData = JSON.parse("{{ data|safe }}");
```

Comment: I tried that before. I read your comment on a similar question. But I am getting a syntax error: "missing ) after argument list". In my HTML `{{ data|safe }}` renders as expected.