# JSON.parse() failing with the result of json_script template tag

Tags: json, django

I'm using the template tag json_script like in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script)

This is my code:

```
{{rules|json_script:"rules"}}

<script lang="javascript">

    const rules = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('rules').textContent)

</script>
```

This is the view function in django:

```
def import_consumptions(request):
    try:

        rules = Rule.objects.all()
        rules = serializers.serialize('json', rules)

        context = {}
        context['title'] = 'Importar consumos'
        context['view_name'] = 'import_consumptions'
        context['menu_group'] = MENU_GROUP
        context['rules'] = rules

        return render(request, "import_consumptions.html", context)

    except:

        template = loader.get_template( 'pages/error-404.html' )
        return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

The problem is what I get from that tag, which is something like this:

[{\"model\": \"rules.rule\", \"pk\": 1, \"fields\": {\"string\": \"adm\", \"profile\": 40 ...

So I get this error:

```
VM1913:5 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token R in JSON at position 5
```

in the JSON.parse line

Could someone help me?

Comment: It looks like `rules` is a *string*, not a dictionary, list, etc.

Comment: I think you are double json encoding rules value

Comment: @AngelQuesada: can you please show relevant parts o your view how you "calculate' `rules`, and pass it to the context?

Comment: Question edited, thank you so much guys

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57913828, https://stackoverflow.com/q/42494823

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove the line:

```py
rules = serializers.serialize('json', rules)
```

The `json_script` tag expects an object on its input. But with the mentioned line, you are converting object to json string.