# Why does typeof JSON.parse returns string

Tags: javascript, bottle

### Brief Explanation

I'm using bottle.py as a simple web server and I'm rendering a javascript, passing it a python dictionary, then in the javascript file I want to add another field to the object and make a post request with the result.

However when i log the typeof datain `likePost()` returns string, so I can't add the new property to the object.

Also I tried without `JSON.Stringify()` and returns the following error: `Unexpected token ' in JSON at position`

### Code

```
    function commentPost(post){
        var comment = prompt("Comment:", "Great post I like it")
        data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(post))
        console.log(typeof data)                      // RETURNS STRING
        data.comment = comment                        // THIS DOESN'T WORK
        fetch("/post", {
            method: "POST", 
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        }).then(res => {
            likePost(data)       
        });

    }
```

Console.log(post)

```
{'hashtag': 'landscapephotography', 'shortcode': 'B_5b0IWqrRU', 'display_url': 'https://scontent-mad1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/s1080x1080/95910887_233194497953707_7239044831960646903_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-mad1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=107&_nc_ohc=i179pDQmui0AX82O3nB&oh=676ca07cba3af57944abcba4d3a27ad2&oe=5EDE8D74', 'thumbnail_src': 'https://scontent-mad1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/s640x640/95910887_233194497953707_7239044831960646903_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-mad1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=107&_nc_ohc=i179pDQmui0AX82O3nB&oh=1ff2ac0b031bcc7cbdbb64b2a661ea1b&oe=5EDF0745', 'is_video': False, 'comments_disabled': False, 'caption': 'Photo by Jelen Girona on May 07, 2020.', 'comments_count': 0, 'timestamp': 1588877630, 'owner': '15642627659', 'likes_count': 0}
```

Console.log(typeof post)

`string`

Comment: Why are you stringifying a JSON and then parsing it? Is `post` not valid JSON?

Comment: @Ashley otherwise it gives the error Unexpected token as I said, and the post variable is a python dictionary

Comment: What is post ? share that data in question

Comment: You should log `data` and take a look, it is most likely this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42494823/json-parse-returns-string-instead-of-object

Comment: It sounds to me like `post` might be a (serialised) JSON string retrieved from the backend, in which case you should just `JSON.parse` it, without first stringifying again. Of course that's just a guess without seeing what it is.

Comment: It sounds like you just `print(dict)` in Python without properly JSON-encoding it, resulting in something that looks suspiciously close to being JSON but being invalid after all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While your `typeof post` is of `string` then you just need to use `JSON.parse`.

The reason this fails, is because a valid JSON can only have [double quotes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#JSON.parse_does_not_allow_single_quotes)(also check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON#Full_JSON_syntax) for the full JSON syntax). Try:

```js
JSON.parse(post.replace(/\'/g, '"'))
```

---

For your case though (I just saw your updated question), your source seems to return `False` with the first letter capitalized and you will get a new error after trying the above.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token F in JSON at position 617

If you can't make your API return it properly, you will have to `.replace` it as well.

```js
const post = "{'hashtag': 'landscapephotography', 'shortcode': 'B_5b0IWqrRU', 'display_url': 'https://scontent-mad1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/s1080x1080/95910887_233194497953707_7239044831960646903_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-mad1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=107&_nc_ohc=i179pDQmui0AX82O3nB&oh=676ca07cba3af57944abcba4d3a27ad2&oe=5EDE8D74', 'thumbnail_src': 'https://scontent-mad1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/s640x640/95910887_233194497953707_7239044831960646903_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-mad1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=107&_nc_ohc=i179pDQmui0AX82O3nB&oh=1ff2ac0b031bcc7cbdbb64b2a661ea1b&oe=5EDF0745', 'is_video': False, 'comments_disabled': False, 'caption': 'Photo by Jelen Girona on May 07, 2020.', 'comments_count': 0, 'timestamp': 1588877630, 'owner': '15642627659', 'likes_count': 0}"

const postObject = JSON.parse(post.replace(/\'/g, '"').replace(/False/g, 'false'));
console.log(postObject);
```

I would suggest you also check `true`. Maybe your source/API/backend also returns it with the first letter capitalized and cause your code to break at a later time.

Comment: Yeah, that was it . It seems that as Python uses single quotes and capitalized booleans i have to do the substitution.